# Laravel Telescope Failed to open stream: no such file or directory TelescopeServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to use [the Telescope package](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/telescope) from Laravels official documentation and I followed the first 2 steps:

```
composer require laravel/telescope
```

and

```
php artisan telescope:install
```

Everything went fine in my command line untill the install. I got the error:

> ErrorException : file_get_contents(path\app\Providers/TelescopeServiceProvider.php: failed to open stream: No such file or directory at: vendor\laravel\telescope\src\Console\InstallCommand.php

So, of course, I googled the issue and found [this](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/732) and I checked to see if my provider's folder exists. It does and indeed the `TelescopeServiceProvider.php` is not there. I tried to run the command `php artisan telescope:install` again and it provided me the message:

> Telescope scaffolding installed successfully.

which I thought was strange but ok, I went to the next step of the documentation:

- After installing the Telescope, you should also run the `migrate` command:
  `php artisan migrate`

So I ran that command and I got the message:

> Nothing to migrate.

So obviously this didn't go right. I checked after the "fake" installed successfully message if the TelescopeServiceProvider exists now but it still didn't.

What did I do wrong and how do I fix this issue?

Comment: I think that the telescope installation failed and for some reason (maybe permissions?) Laravel couldn't create the `TelescopeServiceProvider` class in your app/Providers folder... Remove the package, run a `composer update` and run the process again (require -> install)... If after the `php artisan telescope:install` you don't see the provider class, the assets inside public folder and the config file than there's a problem with filesystem permission IMHO

Comment: You can try to download the missing service provider from github, add it to the Providers directory manually and then run `telescope:install`.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/732#issuecomment-542988625 Other people addressing the issue

Answer (score 5):

Try update Telescope,

```
composer update --prefer-source
```

Try removing Telescope and then reinstalling the package as the installation seems to have broken the package:

```
composer remove laravel/telescope
composer require laravel/telescope
```

Try:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or:

```
artisan cache:clear
```

after you update or make changes to `composer.json` to refresh everything.

Comment: This still doesn't do anything for me. I still have nothing to migrate after installing telescope. It seems as if the install went wrong but it still proceeded.

Comment: @Loko what if you fire `composer update --prefer-source`?

Comment: @Loko OK. So remove Telescope: `composer remove laravel/telescope` and then reinstall it: `composer require laravel/telescope`. Make sure you have the correct permissions to modify the files.

Comment: Nope. I reinstalled it, but it's still giving me the `nothing to migrate` message

Comment: This time there weren't any errors no. It really seems as if the first time messed everything up.

Comment: Then I'd suggest removing `vendor` and reinstalling all the packages. But, make a backup, just in case.

Comment: Please verify if there is a telescope record in your migrations table? If so, remove it before reinstalling.

Comment: @BramVerstraten There is no telescope record in my migrations table.

Comment: @Loko your migrations might be out of sync, copy your db, then run `php artisan migrate:fresh`.

Comment: Thats not the issue though since there is not even a migration after the telescope install when there is supposed to be something to migrate as the documentation states.

Comment: Please verify your composer phar with `composer diagnose`. Update when needed with `composer self-update`.

Comment: @BramVerstraten `composer diagnose` gives me all **OK**. Nothing wrong there

Comment: Hello the composer dump-auto will fix the problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Per
[the Telescope Github Issues](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/746)

Telescope is not ready for Laravel 6 yet. Many people are having this same issue. The solution is to look at [this issue.](https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/732)
Although it is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

use **composer dump-autoload**

and:

**artisan cache:clear**

but

**install composer require brick/math**

its work