# Laravel Telescope

Tags: laravel, telescope

I removed a composer package, with composer remove laravel/telescope But getting to the end of the command output I got

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider' not found
```

I deleted the vendor folder, check to make sure the package is not in the composer.json file, reinstalled the vendor packages and I got the same error at the end of the command output

Answer (score 0):

Delete manually all the files in your `bootstrap/cache` directory and you should be fine

Comment: does not work  bootstrap\cache directory must b
  e present and writable.

Comment: In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Yes, that's why I said to remove every file, not the directory

Comment: its worked   for that issue        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098157/laravel-telescope-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-telescopeserv?rq=1